# C: difference between (int)x and floor(x)?

Tags: c, floating-point

In C, what is the difference between these two?

```
float myF = 5.6;

printf( "%i \n", (int)myF ); // gives me "5"
printf( "%ld \n", floor(myF) ); // also "5"?
```

When is one preferable over the other?

Comment: try `floor(-5.5)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast to int vs floor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300290/cast-to-int-vs-floor)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One big difference is that of negative numbers; if you change `myF` to `-5.6`, then casting to an int returns `-5` while `floor(myF)` is `-6`.

As to which is preferable, as a rule of thumb I'd say to only cast to an int if you *know* that's what you need -- and since you're asking here, chances are that you probably want `floor`.

(Also note that with `printf` formatting, `%ld` is a long integer; a double is `%lf`.)

Answer (score 5):

`floor(n)` returns the mathematical floor of `n`, that is, the greatest integer not greater than `n`. `(int)n` returns the truncation of `n`, the integer whose *absolute value* is no greater than that of `n`. Similarly, `ceil(n)` returns the mathematical ceiling of `n`, or the smallest integer not smaller than `n`. As AraK pointed out, the number returned by `floor()` or `ceil()` may not fit within the range of `int`.

Answer (score 3):

When you get the `floor` of double, that "integer" `double` may or mayn't be representable in a variable of type `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The former casts your float value as a integer (and you're using an int specifier in the printf call).

The latter uses floor (from the C math lib) to return a double that has been rounded down.

Comment: Well, yes, you're technically correct. "Math.floor" is not in C. I think you know what I meant. Check my edit.

Comment: Yeah, I did. Sorry if I came off as a jerk. This place tends to turn people a tad self-righteous...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the result as an integer or a double?

If you want a integer, cast; if you want a double, use `floor`.

For example, if you want to get the cosine of the value, you should just use `floor` as `cos` takes a double.

But if you wanted to use the value for `exit` (just picking a random API here), you should cast because `exit` takes an int.