# What are the significant differences with these two PHP equations?

Tags: math, integer, floor

Working example : http://ideone.com/Ond6PY

You have two variables namely `$a = 5` and `$b = 9`

What are the major mathematical differences between these two statements?

`floor(floor($a / $b) - .5); //output: -1`

and

`(int)((int)($a / $b) - .5); //output: 0`

Comment: Guess: `floor` rounds down (to minus infinity), `(int)` truncates (rounds toward 0).

Comment: (int) is a typecast, not a function!

Comment: The tope answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300290/cast-to-int-vs-floor) explains that. Same as zch's comment above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look to the rounding of parts of your expression.

The division of 5/9 is

```
$a / $b = 5 / 9 = 0.555555556
```

so see http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php

```
floor(1.5) = 1
floor(-1.5) = -2
```

then

```
floor(floor($a / $b) - .5) = floor(floor(0.555555556)) = floor(0 - .5) = floor(-.5) = -1
```

and the second case
see http://www.php.net/intval

```
(int) 4.32 = 4
```

then

```
(int)((int)($a / $b) - .5) = (int)((int)(0.555555556) - .5) = (int)(0 - .5) = int(-0.5) = 0;
```

Comment: That's wrong. That's not intval, that's typecasting: look here!: http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: @Sebi2020 Right, even though that's not 'intval', the rounding algorithm is the same. I used the link because there is the explanation of rounding on php.net. If you've a better one edit the answer please.

Comment: Apparently I'm not. I got two downvotes for my answer.

Answer (score -2):

(int) is a typecast and you get an Integer e.g. 2, 3 , 5 etc. floor rounds down.

So with `(int)((int) 5 / 9)-0.5)` you get:

> 0 - 0 (0.56666666) = 0

`(int)` isn't a function! Look here: [Type Casting - PHP DOC](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting)