# pow() returning wrong result under specific conditions (and an unexpected fix) - Why is all this?

Tags: c++, gcc, pow

I have been creating a short program for implementing Sieve of Eratosthenes. In he program, I have used  `int startingPoint` which held the value of the current prime number, which had it's multiplications being marked non-prime, starting from its square. I used the pow() function to calculate the square of the starting point in the current loop. While doing so, I came across a weird phenomenon. When `startingPoint` was equal to `5`, then after `int i = pow(startingPoint,2)` the value of `i` was 24, instead of 25. This phenomenon occurred only when `startingPoint` was equal to 5. Afterwards, I ran a few tests, that leaded to the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int p=5;

    int num1 = pow(5,2);
    int num2 = pow(p,2);
    float num3 = pow(p,2);
    int num4 = floor(pow(p,2));

    std::cout.precision(10);

    std::cout<<num1<<std::endl; //25
    std::cout<<num2<<std::endl; //24
    std::cout<<std::fixed<<num3<<std::endl; //25.0000000000
    std::cout<<num4<<std::endl; //25            
}
```

As it can be seen, if I call `pow` with `int` literals, the result will be the actual square of the number. However, if I call it using `int p=5`, then what `pow` returns is actually one lower than the expected result. If I pass the result into a `float` variable, it also recieves the correct result.

Now, I know the way `pow` calculates powers is via approximation, and thus, errors such as this when converting to integer may occur. I might just let it be like that. But what REALLY made me stop and think is what happens with `num4`. `pow(p,2)` casted to int returns 24. But `floor(pow(p,2))` casted to `int` returns 25. So the `floor` function, which, by standard rounds a number down, somehow makes the returned value cast into a higher integer value.

My question in short: Just how does that happen?
(I was using gcc 5.3.0 through MinGW)

**Edit:** As I already stated in the question, I can accept the reason behind `pow` return value being casted into a lower integer value, but what I really can't comprehend (and I haven't seen this being brought up anywhere else either) is how `floor` fixes that. How can `floor` make the return value of `pow` actually cast into a higher integer value? Now THAT is the real question.

Comment: Why is it tagged [C] and [C++] a the same time? In C++ math functions are overloaded (and can be even in `<math.h>`), which means that you might end up calling completely different functions in these two languages. Your code is C++. Did you try this in C as well? Or did you add [C] tag just because you think these are chiefly C library functions?

Comment: @AnT BTW, I've removed the C tag because `#include <iostream>` and `std::cout` aren't valid C.

Comment: `pow` works on floating points, so rounding problems when converting to `int` make sense; but it does not make sense that the result would be different for `int` variable and `int` constant parameter (`num1` and `num2`). [I cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/v82iWO).

Comment: [Already asked and answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-does-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5-with-my-compiler-and-os). It can't be reproduced unless you're using specific versions of specific compilers, compiled with specific options.

Comment: To calculate `num1` the compiler might have cheated using some optimisation. So in fact it created different code as for calculating `num2`.

Comment: Can anyone explain the different result for `num2 ` and `num4`? OP: can you post the command line used to compile the example?

Comment: I was more than sure that it's a compiler specific occurence, turned out I only get 24 as a result if I compile with -O0, any higher optimization level leads to showing the correct values.

Comment: As a "workaround", `pow(p,2)` can also be written as `p*p`.

Comment: @SinanÜnür This isn't rounding for printing. I don't even see how an integer value could be rounded for printing anyway. But this `pow` function was actually used to initialize a loop variable, and it lead to the loop variable accessing an array on wrong indexes, because of the wrong conversion after pow. With all due respect, I wasn't asking for tips about not using `pow` for integer multiplication, I was asking about the reason behind this occurence, out of sheer curiosity. And although I could understand `pov` returning with a lower `int` value, I can't understand how `floor` fixes that.

Comment: @BoPersson Thank you, but the topic of the question is why this phenomenon occurs, not how to fix it.

Comment: @SinanÜnür `pow` does not, but the returned value is implicitly converted to `int`. And since I'm not printing out the returned value of `pow`, but the `int` variable, we can't possibly be talking about rounding for printing.

Comment: @MrLumie The reason for all of this will be in the generated assembly language.  More than likely (and another comment alluded to this), just because you wrote explicitly `pow(p,2)` in two separate places in your code does **not** guarantee they result in the same assembly code or same set of assembly instructions.  One deals with a temporary that is sent to `floor` the other does not.

Comment: Dupe didn't explain num4 - voted to reopen.

Comment: @MrLumie Are you remembering to link with the math library?

Comment: @Bathsheba I feel that it would benefit from a separate question. / Besides that can be explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517588).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange behaviour of the pow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155883/strange-behaviour-of-the-pow-function)