# Mathematically correct result from Math.sqrt for int arguments?

Tags: java, floating-point, square-root

Given an `int` x, is `(int)Math.sqrt(x)` guaranteed to return the mathematically correct result, truncated to an int (i.e., the exact mathematical value of `floor(sqrt(x))`) for all non-negative `x`?

Comment: Can you specify with mathematically correct result?

Comment: @FailingCoder - I don't understand your question.

Comment: @BeeOnRope do you mind provide an example of an incorrect result and a correct one?

Comment: @ngueno sure, `(int)Math.sqrt(10)` gives 3 which is the correct result, any other result would be an incorrect result. I mean "the exact square root with any fractional part chopped off", i.e,. `floor()` of the exact result.

Comment: The most popular questions seem to be really short. Anyway, my answer would be the same as a currently deleted answer.

Comment: @jasli answered this correctly, then deleted their answer.  The short answer is _yes_.  Please, jasli, will you undelete your answer?  The comment about it not applying for `long` is irrelevant, because all `int` values can be represented exactly by a `double`, whereas the same is untrue for `long`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem - the answer was correct, but I think the reasoning wasn't, or at least it was incomplete? In particular, they didn't mention the "all int values can be represented exactly by a double" part at all. I agree the delete was hasty though! The observation about `long` applies because you could substitute `long` in that answer without contradicting anything, so if the answer fails in that case, the reasoning cannot be complete.

Comment: It would have been a really good answer to keep, as it would keep an example of things an answer would need in this question.

Comment: @FailingCoder agreed, voted to undelete.

Comment: OK, the bit about casting a `double` to an `int` being equivalent to flooring is untrue, but the difference is provably irrelevant.  The key point is that you can't lose information casting `int` to `double`; whereas you _can_ lose information casting `long` to `double` - and jasli didn't mention this.  Perhaps I should write an answer myself.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem - can you give an example over the non-negative `int`s where casting to `int` is not equivalent to `floor`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300290/cast-to-int-vs-floor might help.

Comment: @FailingCoder - well the accepted answer contradicts Dawood: it says the results are only different for negative values, and the deleted answer and my question explicitly refer only to _non-negative values_.

Comment: Exactly. That's the point.

Comment: @FailingCoder - makes sense :).

Comment: Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. *Avoid answering questions in comments.* Oops.

Comment: No, there is no such example over `int`s.  You get into trouble with numbers that are too big for `int`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Java documentation, `Math.sqrt()` returns "the double value closest to the true mathematical square root of the argument value", and casting a `double` to an `int` is equivalent to flooring for non-negative numbers (for negative numbers, `floor()` truncates towards negative infinity while casting truncates towards 0). The only case I can think of where `(int)Math.sqrt(x)` wouldn't do the job is if the result of the square root is too large to fit into an `int`.

**Additional Links**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt(double)

Comment: I don't think this answer is complete, because you could write the same answer with `long` substituted for `int`, but I know for that for `long` it fails, e.g., for `4503599761588224`. The answer can always fit in an `int` because the result of `sqrt` is never larger than the argument (except for fractional values from 0 to 1 which don't apply for int arguments).

Comment: That's a good point, sorry I missed that in the original question.