# Java math.random query, rounding (concept understanding)

Tags: java, class, math, rounding

I'm trying to understand the logic of the math.random or more specifically what is occurring and or why.

I understand essentially with the code below for example due to java being a 0 based language we start at 0 for indexing, etc.

the below code prints out a value between 0 and 10 inclusive.
11 is exclusive as understood.

```
int result = (int) (Math.random () * 11);
```

My question is why for example if we were to get 0.99 * 10 then = 10.99
Why does the number not round up to 11?

Is this simply by design java will always round down to 0? or am I missing a concept?

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Casting to an `int` will result in a `floor`. This means that your number will always get rounded to 0, so 10.99 will become 10 after casting to `int`

Comment: Does this answer your question? Could I submit the answer or do you have other questions?

Comment: I wasn't aware of the floor occurring, Thank-you David I understand now.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments:
Casting to an `int` will result in a `floor`. This means that your number will always get rounded to 0, so 10.99 will become 10 after casting to `int`.

You can look at this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3300439/11023871) as well