# How do I avoid getting -0 when dividing in c++

Tags: c++, division

I have a script in which I want to find the chunk my player is in.
Simplified version:

```
float x = -5
float y = -15
int chunkSize = 16

int player_chunk_x = int(x / chunkSize)
int player_chunk_y = int(y / chunkSize)
```

This gives the chunk the player is in, but when `x` or `y` is negative but not less than the `chunkSize` (-16), `player_chunk_x` or `player_chunk_y` is still `0` or `'-0'` when I need `-1`

Of course I can just do this:

```
if (x < 0) x--
if (y < 0) y--
```

But I was wondering if there is a better solution to my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `x` is negative, `std::floor(x / chunkSize)`? If `x` is positive use `std::ceil` instead?

Comment: I don't believe you. Normally only floating-point types can be `-0`.

Comment: I dont actually get -0 but if the number after the division is between -0.0000001 and -0.9999 i will get 0 when i want -1. I was wondering if I could do this without using if statements

Comment: Conversion from floating point to integer *always* truncates the decimals. And there's no way to get consistent results of rounding without any kind of conditional check for negative or non-negative values.

Comment: Your actual problem seems related to [cast-to-int-vs-floor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300290/cast-to-int-vs-floor).

Comment: BTW: there are no C++ scripts

Comment: As a possible workaround, get the absolute value of the division and always use `std::ceil`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you are casting a floating point value to an integer value.

This rounds to *zero* by default.

If you want consistent round down, you first have to floor your value:

```
int player_chunk_x = int(std::floor(x / chunkSize);
```

Answer (score 4):

Since C++20 it's *impossible* to get an integral type signed negative zero, and was only possible in a rare (but by no means extinct) situation where your platform had 1's complement `int`. It's still possible in C (although rare), and adding 0 to the result will remove it.

It's possible though to have a floating point signed negative zero. For that, adding 0.0 will remove it.

Note that for an integral `-0`, subtracting 1 will yield `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like negative numbers then don't use them:

```
int player_chunk_x = (x - min_x) / chunkSize;
int player_chunk_y = (y - min_y) / chunkSize;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want integer, in this case -1 on ( -5%16 or anything like it ) then this is possible using a math function:

Possible Ways :

1. using floor ->

```
float x = -5;
float y = -15;
int chunkSize = 16;

int player_chunk_x = floor(x / chunkSize) 
// will give -1 for (-5 % 16);
// 0 for (5%16) 
// 1 for any value between 1 & 2 and so on 

int player_chunk_y = floor(y / chunkSize);
```