# INT vs FLOOR in Fortran

Tags: fortran

According to gfortran documentation, [`INT(x)`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/INT.html) and [`FLOOR(x)`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/FLOOR.html) both take input `x` and convert `x` to integer type. `FLOOR` apparently only allows input of type REAL whereas `INT` takes input of type INTEGER, REAL, and complex.

Is the allowed input type the only difference between `INT` and `FLOOR`? If so, can anyone explain why `FLOOR` exists since it is apparently superfluous?

The "Similar Questions" box showed similar Stack Overflow questions in [C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604235/c-difference-between-intx-and-floorx), [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300290/cast-to-int-vs-floor), and [Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31036098/what-is-the-difference-between-int-and-floor-in-python-3), but apparently no one has asked this question for Fortran yet, which led me to getting this deep into asking it.

Including Fortran in my quick searches on [Google](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=difference+between+floor+and+INT+fortran+90) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=int%20fortran%2090) meant nothing useful appeared. So this is admittedly a duplicate (unless Fortran has `INT` and `FLOOR` quirks separating it from C/C++/Python) but I think it will have utility in allowing the result to be more easily/quickly searchable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of `INT` is such that it rounds towards zero for REAL input, while `FLOOR` always rounds down.  Consequently, for negative input, the results differ.

Unlike some of the other languages you reference, the result of calling `FLOOR` in Fortran is of type INTEGER.

Consider `FLOOR` in the context of its cousins `NINT` and `CEILING`.